# Mongodb ObjectId generator as SQL Server proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a hybrid application where part of data (mostly legacy) is stored in SQL Server and another part in Mongodb. I just converted all primary key types in SQL Server to use ObjectId which I generate in the application when inserting new records into SQL Server.
Now, I found that I need to clone some template records (about 10-20 records at a time), and in order to do that I need to be able to generate ObjectId values via a SQL Server function or stored proc.
Is it possible and is there code available?

Comment: Primary key isn't a type in SQL Server (it is a constraint) and, as far as I know, in other relational databases either. Please, give us scripts of the tables in SQL Server and MongoDB, and explain in more details what do you mean by "clone some template records".

Comment: I know that Primary Key is not a type but a constraint, I said that I replaced all primary keys (originally GUID's) in my tables with ObjectID (char(24)). All I'm asking - is there a way to generate new ObjectID values in a SQL server function or stored proc

Comment: Don't use `CHAR` for keys. COLLATION rules apply to them and it will make sorting and indexing much harder. Use any type that compares as bytes and can fit 12 bytes. Some people have suggested NEWID() which returns a UUID (16 bytes).

Comment: I meant compares as binary.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use [NEWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function which generates 16-byte [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx).

But in MongoDB The [BSON ObjectId Datatype](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) is a 12-byte binary value.

Try this

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() as varchar(36)),'-',''),24)
```

Hope, this helps.

**EDITED**

In article [Object IDs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) described BSON ObjectID specification. The format includes:

> 1. TimeStamp. This is a unix style timestamp. It is a signed int representing the number of seconds before or after January 1st 1970
>    (UTC).
> 2. Machine. This is the first three bytes of the (md5) hash of the machine host name, or of the mac/network address, or the virtual
>    machine id.
> 3. Pid. This is 2 bytes of the process id (or thread id) of the process generating the object id.
> 4. Increment. This is an ever incrementing value, or a random number if a counter can't be used in the language/runtime.
>
> The server itself and almost all drivers use the format above.

So, it is **impossible** to generate MongoDB ObjectID in SQL Server.

The only way to solve this problem is to change logic of the application.

Comment: It's not simple binary value, it have strong structure -> http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

Comment: @Andrey Sorry. What do you meen by "it won't be that unique"? Of course, probability of appearence of 2 equal 24-digit numbers greater than of 32-digit numbers but it's still less than probability of me becoming the president of Russia and you of the USA in the same year.

Comment: @AndrewOrsich From the article `BSON ObjectIds can be any 12 byte binary string that is unique`. As far as I understand, there just explaind an algorithm of unique number creation.

Comment: @Igor: Exactly. This is means that if you will create objectid using way provided above it will be not possible to parse result string into objectId from driver.

Comment: @AndrewOrsich Didn't know that. In SQL Server we can edit the string mannualy and than save as uniqueidentifier. In this case answer for the question `is there a way to generate new ObjectID values in a SQL server` is NO and @Andrey needs to change logic of the application.

Comment: @Igor: I think so. Also i guess you can add result of our discussion as part of your answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible in SQL Server? A couple of possibilities come to mind. One is using an external assembly (managed code object) written in C# that produces BINARY(12) results that can be used as values for a BINARY(12) primary key column. The other is that maybe you can write this as a stored procedure that produces these values because timestamp, machine host name, PID, and increment are all available in TSQL. This assumes that the correct logic can be expressed in TSQL.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I was trying to do the same thing. This is what I came up with on SQL Server 2012.

```
Create Function NewObjectId(@counter binary(3))
returns binary(12)
begin

    declare @epoch datetime2, @seconds binary(4), @process binary(2), @hostname binary(3)
    set @epoch = '1/1/1970'

    select @seconds = cast(Datediff(ss, @epoch, getutcdate()) as binary(4))
    select @hostname = cast(HashBytes('MD5', HOST_NAME()) as binary(3))
    select @process = cast(@@SPID as binary(2))

    declare @objectId binary(12)
    select @objectId = (@seconds + @hostname + @process + @counter)

    return @objectId
end
```

This can be called like this:

```
select NewObjectId(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3))
```

The reason CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3) is passed in is because calling that function is apparently side-effecting and it can't be used inside another function. I would have preferred to use an incrementing sequence for the counter portion, but a random number works as well.

Also, I noticed that you said you are using a char(24) to store the value. This returns a binary(12) since that's what the MongoDB ObjectIds are. Using binary(12) also requires half of the space to store the value.

I'm sure this isn't helpful now, but it was a fun problem to solve.

I'm going to try taking my ObjectID C# code and see if I can load it as a CLR function into SQL Server. That might give better results and performance.

Comment: That's what I just commented above under @igor-borisenko's answer. I honestly think your answer is probably the best answer one could have written for this question.